# Wifi doesn't reconnect to known network

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, 4.3-jelly-bean

My phone fails to connect to wifi networks it has been connected to before.  When this happens, even if I reenter the password it will not connect.  But if I restart the device, it connects to the network without my having to enter the password.  This happens both at work and at home.  It's a Samsung Galaxy Stardust running Android 4.3.

---

I don't know if this is an answer, but my problem has gone away.  Here's what happened.  I called TracFone tech support about this.  The representative told me to shut the phone off, pull out the battery, and see if the battery had a red sticker on it.  It didn't.  Then she told me to put the battery back, and that the next step would be to do a hard reset.  When I found that doing so would erase my settings and contacts and such, I declined.  So I thought I had wasted my time.  But the wifi problem has not happened since then.  It's certainly not the only time I turned the phone off, so I have to think that taking the battery out for a couple of seconds reset something.

Comment: No idea what's causing that, but as a work-around: Try switching to airplane mode and back might be a little more convenient than restarting the device.

Comment: @Izzy, it actually takes 3 steps: airplane mode on, airplane mode off, and wifi back on.  Probably quicker than a restart, but more work.

Comment: If WiFi was before switching to airplane mode, it should be on after switching airplane mode off. To minimize steps, you could utilize an [automation](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) tool like [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info), to place a shortcut for a task on your homescreen – then it would be a single tap.

Comment: @Izzy, yes, you'd think that if wifi was on at the start, it would come back on after airplane mode is turned off, but that's not what I experience when wifi was in the weird on-but-nonfunctional state I've been seeing.

Comment: I have something similar with my Nexus 10 with Android 5.1.1, it happens now & then. I looked into `About` and then `Status` and saw, that it has received 2 IPv6 addresses, but none for IPv4. Turning wlan off and on again fixes it.